# How to Group by 6 days in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by

I want to convert this type of data to 6Days GROUP BY format.

```
+-----+--------------+------------+
| gid |     cnt      |    date    |
+-----+--------------+------------+
|  1  |     1        | 2012-02-05 |
|  2  |     2        | 2012-02-06 |
|  3  |     1        | 2012-02-07 |
|  4  |     1        | 2012-02-08 |
|  5  |     1        | 2012-02-09 |
|  6  |     2        | 2012-02-10 |
|  7  |     3        | 2012-02-11 |
|  8  |     1        | 2012-02-12 |
|  9  |     1        | 2012-02-13 |
| 10  |     2        | 2012-02-14 |
| 11  |     3        | 2012-02-15 |
| 12  |     4        | 2012-02-16 |
| 13  |     1        | 2012-02-17 |
| 14  |     1        | 2012-02-18 |
| 15  |     1        | 2012-02-19 |
| 16  |    NULL      | 2012-02-20 |
| 17  |     6        | 2012-02-21 |
| 18  |    NULL      | 2012-02-22 |
+-----+--------------+------------+
```

↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

[image]

The date is a continuous format.

Comment: Really? A screenshot of plain text? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: can you elaborate question more?

Comment: This is not really Group by as you have records that are being taken into account twice... like 10-02-2012.

Comment: Copy-paste the text, after you paste it, mark it and than use Ctrl+K to change it to code format

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need something like this:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT date::date, (random() * 3)::int AS cnt FROM generate_series('2012-02-05'::date, '2012-02-22'::date, '1 day'::interval) AS date
) 
SELECT start::date,
       (start + '5 day'::interval)::date AS end,
       sum(cnt)
  FROM generate_series(
                (SELECT min(date) FROM x),
                (SELECT max(date) FROM x),
                '5 day'::interval
       ) AS start
  LEFT JOIN x ON (x.date >= start AND x.date <= start + '5 day'::interval)
 GROUP BY 1, 2 
 ORDER BY 1
```

In `x` I emulate your table.